# Updating iOS core data with web service JSON

Tags: ios, json, web-services, core-data

Let's say there I have an app that has model structure "Teams" and it's respective "members". This app then pulls data from a web service in json. How does the web service communicate which data has changed and how?

I'm thinking it passes certain JSON keys to notify the app which kinds of updates have occurred. For example:

{"operations": [{"delete":"member1"}, {"add": team2}, {"rename": team3} ... ]}

What are the conventions of doing this?

Edit 1: I am not looking for frameworks that solve this problem. I just want to conceptually know how this is usually done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the app will ask the server: "What has changed since XXX" and the server will reply with the objects that have changed since that date.  The server generally gives full objects for the app to parse and consume.

With that assumption you can get the response from the server and then walk the objects in the JSON payload, loading objects that exist and updating them and then inserting new objects that do not exist locally.

Deletes can be more challenging as most servers that I have seen won't tell you about them.  If you control the server then you could send a response with identifiers to objects that have been deleted since the last update.